# force redirect after login form is submitted

Tags: php, forms, redirect, form-submit

I was trying to make the php contact form in this tut [Advanced jQuery contact form with php support](http://www.tutorialstag.com/advanced-jquery-contact-form-with-php-support.html) to redirect to another page .i.e. thanks-you page or whatever page I want, but so far no luck with that. I thought I just need to write the `header('Location: http://www.mydomain/folder1');` or using another way `header( "refresh:5;url=index.php" );`
and should work, but it didn't.

I bit there is something wrong I do here, but not sure exactly where!!

any idea how to achieve this task...!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`header('Location: http://www.mydomain/folder1');` is the way to do a redirect.
notice the command is submitted in the header of the page respond. so if there has been any output so far the header can not be manipulated. 
maybe thats the reason it doesn't work in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I used that function, but when I submit the form, the whole redirected page comes in the place of the form, which is none sense...

Answer (score 1):

The refresh command is interpreted at the browser level, which can be ignored at the client side. You can perform a forced redirect from the server by using commands such as those described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.force-redirect.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's too general. I want to know more specific answer because I was playing with these stuff last few days and none worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure to call ob_start() and make sure outout buffering is on?

Comment: thanks for the reply, but why do I have use that function anyways??